# Replaces data in a matrix with Matlab

Tags: matrices, matlab

A is a matrix (6 ×6) defined as:
A= [0.25    0.35    0.46    0.56    0.67    0.78;
    0.25    0.37    0.49    0.61    0.73    0.86;
    0.25    0.38    0.52    0.66    1.80    1.94;
    0.25    0.40    0.55    0.71    1.86    1.92;
    0.25    0.42    0.59    1.76    1.93    1.96;
    0.25    0.43    1.62    1.81    1.98    1.99]

I want to create a matrix B with the same variables as the data set of the matrix A, but replace the data that is greater than 1 by the number 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple, just use the following command.

`B=(A<=1).*A+(A>1).*2`

Some additional comments: 
`A<=1` generates a 0/1 matrix of the same size as `A` which is equal to 1 whenever the the respective entry of `A`is $\leq1$. `A>1` works accordingly.